# How do I extend a JAXBContext used by classes generated by CXF wsdl2java to include an additional ObjectFactory

Tags: xml, cxf, jax-ws, wsdl2java, sabre

**What?**

I am using CXF's wsdl2java to generate Java classes from an externally supplied wsdl (`TravelItineraryReadRQ.wsdl`). 
When I call the operation, I get a response that I can unmarshal into Java classes, with the exception of one element and its children which default to DOM elements (`ElementNSImpl`)

**What's special about this element?**

The element in question (`PriceQuote`) is of type (`PriceQuoteType`) defined in the OpenReservation schema as `xs:any`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="PriceQuoteType">
  <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:any processContents="strict"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**Why does this happen?**

The element that I receive (a `PriceQuoteInfo` element) belongs to a namespace that is not referenced in this wsdl, so none of the `ObjectFactory` classes that the `JAXBContext` has been created with, can unmarshal the element. It therefore ends up as raw DOM elements (`ElementNSImpl`).

**Do I have the schema where the `PriceQuoteInfo` type is defined?**

Yes, I have obtained this, and run `wsdl2java` on it to generate Java classes for it and appended them to the classpath.

**What have I tried?**

To enable the `PriceQuoteInfo` to be unmarshalled independently, I created an external binding file to annotate the `PriceQuoteInfo` as an `XmlRootElement` and referenced this file in the maven build:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">    
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../PriceQuoteServices_v.3.0.0.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
       <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='PriceQuoteInfo.Get.Response']">
            <jaxb:class name="PQSPriceQuoteInfo"/>
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="PriceQuoteInfo" namespace="http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/pqs/1.0"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
```

**Partial Success**

I'm then able to unmarshal `PriceQuoteInfo` XML independently, using a `JAXBContext` initialised as the following:

> JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PQSPriceQuoteInfo.class)

When unmarshalling `PriceQuoteInfo` as a child of a `TravelItineraryReadRS` element, I can also unmarshal it by declaring the `JAXBContext` as:

```
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TravelItineraryReadRS.class, PQSPriceQuoteInfo.class)
```

or alternatively, by using their object factories:

```
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.sabre.services.res.tir.v3_10.ObjectFactory.class, com.sabre.ns.ticketing.pqs.v1_0.ObjectFactory.class)
```

**And what does the unmarshalling code look like?**

```
    InputStream inputStream = MyUnitTest.getResourceAsStream(filename)
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller()
    JAXBElement<TravelItineraryReadRS> travelItineraryReadRS = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(inputStream), TravelItineraryReadRS.class)
```

And this unmarshals some `TravelItineraryReadRS` XML into Java classes, without any raw DOM objects.

**So what's the problem?**

When I call this service via CXF / JAX-WS the `PriceQuoteInfo` unmarshals into raw DOM elements as I haven't found a way of modifying the `JAXBContext` that it uses to add the missing object factory.

**@XmlSeeAlso**

The `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the wsdl's generated *PortType interface contains a list of `ObjectFactory` classes.
By replicating and extending the `TravelItineraryReadPortType` interface and adding `com.sabre.ns.ticketing.pqs.v1_0.ObjectFactory` to the list in the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation, I succeeded in triggering an XML validation error during unmarshalling of some children of the PriceQuoteInfo element:

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/pqs/1.0", local:"ValidatingCarrier")
```

Although not very elegant it shows that this approach is attempting to unmarshal the `PriceQuoteInfo` rather than leaving it as DOM objects, but that the XML isn't exactly matching the `GetPriceQuote` schema I generated. I'll either turn off validation or find a matching schema to resolve that.

**The Question**

Is it possible to influence the `JAXBContext` used in a CXF / JAX-WS web service call so as to add the `ObjectFactory` for `PriceQuoteInfo` to the generated *PortType?

For example: is there a way of influencing the generated @XmlSeeAlso annotation so that it includes this ObjectFactory, by using external bindings?

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem. I found no way to influence `JAXBContext` directly but I was able to inject my ObjectFactory via `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setProperties()` when creating the JAX-WS proxy:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setProperties(
    Collections.singletonMap(
                "jaxb.additionalContextClasses",
                new Class[{com.mypackage.ObjectFactory.class});
```

This way I got `JAXBElement<T>` instead of raw DOM objects (`T` would be `PriceQuoteInfo` in your case).
Hope that helps.

Comment: You have a syntax mistake, correct is: factory.setProperties(
                Collections.singletonMap(
                        "jaxb.additionalContextClasses",
                        new Class[]{ObjectFactory.class}));